# How to get a count of records by unique time spans?

Tags: sql

I've got a table that has a series of start dates and end dates, and I'm trying to figure out how many unique sessions exist--in other words, how many distinct time periods that don't overlap.

So if the table looks like this:

```
ID   |   StartTime   |   EndTime
 A   |  1/1/11 12:00 | 1/1/11 14:00
 B   |  1/1/11 12:30 | 1/1/11 15:00
 C   |  1/1/11 14:30 | 1/1/11 15:30
 D   |  1/1/11 16:00 | 1/1/11 16:30
 E   |  1/1/11 16:30 | 1/1/11 17:00
```

what kind of query would return a count of 3 sessions since records A, B and C overlap?

Comment: How do you decide to keep A instead of B?

Comment: it doesn't matter, all I want returned is a count.  So if a query can tell me that there are 3 unique sessions, I won't mind if it's excluding A or B.

Comment: Also, what if two time spans overlap, but are not fully containing? Say B was 12:30 - 15:00. It overlaps A, but neither fully contains the other. Would you want both, neither, only one in result set?

Comment: Well what makes A unique but B not unique?  I would assume they would BOTH be excluded from the count since they overlap (and are therefore both not unique)

Comment: Also, to your answer to @JNK, it actually MIGHT matter whether you keep A or B. Say you have a 5th element, E, and it goes from 13:05 - 13:25. If you picked A over B, it would NOT include E. However, if you picked B over A, it WOULD include E.

Comment: @king14nyr - That's a really good question--I hadn't thought of that.  It might make it a little trickier, but overlaps that are not fully contained would still count as a single session.  So with the case you came up with, it would still count as 3 sessions overall.

Comment: thanks for the help--I just edited the question to include these cases and to clarify that I was only looking for a count.  As for the new question about if there was a record that slightly overlapped either A or B, that would have to be excluded from the count as well since for the purposes of this query they'd all be considered a single session.

Comment: So you essentially want your results to be: (A,B,C: 12:00 - 15:30) (D: 16:00 - 16:30) (E: 16:30 - 17:00)

Comment: Does an exact match count as overlap?  If one session ends at `12:00` and another starts at `12:00` are we counting that as 1 or 2 sessions?

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the clarifications. Looking for the number of mutually exclusive sessions... :)

Comment: @JNK, based on his initial description, it sounds like an exact match is not considered an overlap, since he counted D & E as separate results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  Returns correct count in SQL Server 2008.

```
DECLARE @t table (id char(1), Starttime smalldatetime, endtime smalldatetime)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
('A','1/1/11 12:00','1/1/11 14:00'),
('B','1/1/11 12:30','1/1/11 15:00'),
('C','1/1/11 14:30','1/1/11 15:30'),
('D','1/1/11 16:00','1/1/11 16:30'),
('E','1/1/11 16:30','1/1/11 17:00')


select 
  count(t.id)
from
  @t t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1 FROM @t t2
                    WHERE (t.starttime > t2.starttime
                    AND t.endtime < t2.starttime)
                    OR (t.starttime < t2.starttime
                    AND t.endtime > t2.starttime) )
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote on a working answer with sample table?

Comment: This seems to be passing all of my tests

Comment: @JNK I ran it through some test cases and can't figure out why this one doesn't work with your formula--I see it as one session but it comes back as 2.  I thought I would be able to edit your statement to handle this case, but apparently I'm even boolean-weaker than I thought...

VALUES
('J','1/1/11 14:01','1/1/11 14:03'),
('K','1/1/11 14:02','1/1/11 14:03'),
('L','1/1/11 14:02','1/1/11 14:04')

Comment: @sXe - if you are looking at 3 part overlaps this code probably won't work.  That's a much more complicated relationship to navigate.

Comment: @JNK - well you definitely answered my question as I'd asked it, so thanks again

Comment: @sXe - no problem.  You may want to ask a new one about the multiple-level overlaps.  I think it will require a CTE or something similar for recursion.